# What's a good way to set the Item or DataSource attribute of a FieldRenderer?

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, webforms, sitecore6

The scenario is that I have a lot of FieldRenderers. These should output data from various places, some from item X and others from item Y. And should be outputting properties from item Z.

Assuming I have a public property `ItemX` that I want to output a property from, any of the following would be OK. But I get no output by any of them:

```
<sc:FieldRenderer runat="server" FieldName="Logo" DataSource="<%# ItemX %>" />
<sc:FieldRenderer runat="server" FieldName="Logo" DataSource="<%= ItemX.Paths.FullPath %>" />
<sc:FieldRenderer runat="server" FieldName="Logo" Item="<%# ItemX %>" />
<sc:FieldRenderer runat="server" FieldName="Logo" Item-ID="<%# ItemX.ID %>" />
<sc:FieldRenderer runat="server" FieldName="Logo" Item-ID-Guid="<%# ItemX.ID.Guid %>" />
```

If I add an ID `MyFieldRenderer` to it and do the ugly piece below, I get correct output:

```
MyFieldRenderer.Item = ItemX;
```

There must be a better way to do this? I'm not sure if this is a Sitecore-specific or WebForms question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible to set the datasource of a FieldRenderer to a server side object without using code behind.  This is a consequence of how WebForms works.  The issue is described in a [Microsoft Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112):

> The <%= ... %> displaying expression is an equivalent of the embedded code block that contains only the Response.Write(…) statement. This is the simplest way to display information such as a single string, an int variable, or a constant. [...] **Remember that the displaying expression cannot be used in the attributes of server controls. This is because the .NET Framework directly compiles the whole expression instead of the displaying content as the value to the attribute.**

In other words, .NET wants to compile the sc:FieldRenderer, and so does not have access to the run-time contents of <%= ItemX.Paths.FullPath %>.  You can see this issue in simpler form by trying to display:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" Text="<%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>" />
```

which renders **<%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>** inside the text box.  In short, you cannot get anything other than a static string inside a server control attribute.

---

There are several possible solutions to this issue:

1. In your Page_Load method, set the Item field of the FieldRenderer, as you describe.  This is the best approach if the number of sublayouts that need to use this logic is limited.
2. You can create an ItemXFieldRenderer subclass that binds Item to ItemX:

   ```
    class ItemXFieldRenderer: FieldRenderer {
      public ItemXFieldRenderer() {
          Item = [code to retrieve ItemX];
      }
    }
   ```

   Then you can use this control anywhere in your solution where you want to render a field from ItemX.  This is the best approach if a large number of sublayouts need to use this logic and the number of items you might need to bind to is very limited.
3. You could create a subclass of FieldRenderer that parses a string property and uses logic to map the string value to the correct item.
4. If the path to ItemX is constant, you can set the full path in the Datasource property like this:

   ```
   <sc:FieldRenderer runat="server" FieldName="Logo"
   DataSource="/sitecore/context/home/some/item" />
   ```

   You can also use a relative path. For example, if the context item has a child folder called "Sources", which in turn has a child item "Default", you could reference in your FieldRenderer with this syntax:

   ```
   <sc:FieldRenderer runat="server" FieldName="Logo"
   DataSource="sources/default" />
   ```

   Per my testing, the evaluation of the datasource is case-insensitive, and Sitecore Query expressions like "../.." and "//*[@@name='value']" do not work.
5. You can use databinding to force ASCX to read the property, as recommended in this [Forums thread](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?postid=29371):

   ```
   <sc:FieldRenderer id="myRenderer" FieldName="Logo" 
   DataSource=<%# ItemX.Paths.FullPath %> />
   ```

   And in codebehind, add

   ```
   myRenderer.DataBind();
   ```

   With this last approach you are still using codebehind, but the decision of which FieldRenderer uses which item is now contained in the markup.  And as Christian Hagelid [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13427050/402949), you can call this.DataBind() on the sublayout to force DataBind to execute recursively on all controls on the page.
6. You can use ASP.NET's ExpressionBuilder syntax to centralize the location of your datasource paths.  There are three ways of doing this:

   - Places your paths in Web.config.  Add this to the <AppSettings> section of Web.config:

     `<add key="ItemX" value="/sitecore/content/path/to/itemx" />`
     Then set the DataSource attribute to:

     `DataSource=<%$ AppConfig: ItemX %>`
   - Place the paths in a .resx resource file in App_GlobalSettings.  If the file is named Paths.resx, you can access its settings with this syntax:

     `DataSource=<%$ Resources: Paths,ItemX %>`
   - You can build an [ExpressionBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.expressionbuilder.aspx) class to build logic to translate a string value to a path.  Note that the ExpressionBuilder is evaluated at Parse time, so you will not have access to the Sitecore context.  This does not look straightforward: the expression builder needs to be referenced in Web.config and the code needs to reside in App_Code.

Comment: Your suggestions 1, 2 and 5 are not really solutions to the problem, because they will lead to an equal amount of duplicated code per data source item as my initial problem (your suggestion #1). For the record, I think suggestion #2 is horrible :) #4 is not scalable and duplicates paths all over the place. #3 requires exchanging all existing FieldRenderers (which is a risky "Replace All" operation in a large project), but is actually a valid suggestion.

Comment: Ouch! I sort of liked #2 ;) but I agree it's not scalable if the number of items is more than one or two.  (I was searching for something that would allow you to keep all your changes in ASCX.)  I've added a section on ExpressionBuilders, which would allow you to keep your paths consolidated.  The solution you came up with looks reasonable, but I would lean to #3, and reference a StringToPath reference class.

Comment: It was creative, I'll give you that! But in my recent projects, we've had structures with 40+ referrable "key items". Thank you for the last solution #6, it is interesting because calling `.DataBind()` on controls make them output ViewState data. Building an ExpressionBuilder class where you could reference item ID's directly from the markup, avoids that extra data. Its only limitation is that the page need to be compiled (using `CodeBehind` instead of `CodeFile`) but I guess that most projects compile their pages/controls anyway. I'll write a complete answer based on this suggestion!

Comment: I'm accepting your answer based on your suggestion #6. Using the built-in ExpressionBuilder class `Resources` (compiled) or `AppConfig` (configurable) to store item IDs is by far the best solution to this problem, and at the same time creates an initial good structure. The item IDs are also easily reachable from code-behind using this method. Thank you for your efforts!

Comment: Thanks Simeon, glad I could help. I learned a ton researching this. :)

Comment: As of today `<sc:FieldRenderer runat="server" FieldName="Logo" Item="<%# ItemX %>" />` syntax works. :D

Answer (score 4):

If you have a lot of FieldRenderer controls and you want to contain the logic inside the markup then you can use the <%# ... %> expression and just call this.DataBind(); at the end of Page.Load. That will then bind all the controls inside your usercontrol.

Comment: Doesn't this have a performance impact? Imagine 10+ sublayouts on a page with 30 controls in each that are data-bound (some unnecessarily). I think this should be a comment since it's not an answer in itself but merely a tip, BTW, but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: If you have a lot of other controls inside your usercontrol then yes this might not be the best solution for you. It depends how your controls are structured. Based on the information in your question I thought this would solve your problem quite elegantly

Comment: This is definitely the easiest way to solve the original problem.  It has the additional advantage of working the same way when you use FieldRenderers in controls that will already be data-bound... like Repeater, ListView, etc.  Your code will be consistent.  Performance hit will be negligible unless this page is being hit dozens (maybe hundreds) of times/second.

Comment: Maybe consistent code, but there's too much boilerplate involved here. It reduces the code from one `.DataBind()` for each repeater to one, but it is based on the item being set-up in code-behind on every sublayout using the item. It also creates unnecessary ViewState output. It's overall not a good, maintainable solution. Dan Solovay provided a better overall solution, and one of the winning points is that his solution doesn't require any set-up of item fields/properties in code-behind.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want to be able to do this on the front-end like in MVC-style and not in the code-behind, but that scenario seems to pose that a front-end FieldRenderer control may not be the right tool. I obviously saw the code you wrote in your answer but why not do this then, all on the front-end:

```
<%= FieldRenderer.Render(item, "field name") %>
```

E.g.

```
<%= FieldRenderer.Render(ItemX, "Logo") %>
```

Comment: This is not "all on the front-end" since it requires setting up `item` (or `ItemX`) in the code-behind. But although surpassed by the true "front-end-only" solutions by Dan Solovay, it's a good suggestion to the initial question

Comment: Right, I guess that was based on your statement "Assuming I have a public property ItemX" -- so I was showing how to do it with no additional C#. You will always need some sort of C# to get access to your items.