# How to fetch the Item Property/Fields in Sitecore?

Tags: c#, sitecore

I am trying to fetch a field called footer from the Item FooterComponent and want to display.This is the code I have tried but cannot fetch and display.

cs code:

```cs
Item footerText=Sitecore.content.Database.GetItem(GUID);
string MyFooter=FooterText["Footer"];
txtFooter.Item = MyFooter;
```

ascx code:

```xml
<sc:fieldrenderer runat="server" id="txtFooter" fieldname="Footer"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not set a string value of the field to the field renderer. Just set correct item and field name:

```cs
Item footerTextItem = Sitecore.content.Database.GetItem(GUID);
txtFooter.Item = footerTextItem;
```

```xml
<sc:fieldrenderer runat="server" id="txtFooter" fieldname="Footer"/>
```

See more information here: https://sitecoresandbox.com/tag/fieldrenderer/

Also read [What's a good way to set the Item or DataSource attribute of a FieldRenderer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423218/whats-a-good-way-to-set-the-item-or-datasource-attribute-of-a-fieldrenderer)